# Dynamically configurable proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, openresty

We have a fleet of IoT devices, and want to proxy a port to an end user (remote diagnostics sessions). In order to avoid exposing the IP of our IoT devices, we want to proxy it to an end user. However, these IPs can be dynamic, and the proxy will of course need to be authenticated.

So the flow will be like this:

1. The user requests a remote diagnostic session;
2. Backend sends request to IoT device to check if the diagnostic service is running, and otherwise starts it;
3. IoT device starts the diagnostic service and replies with the status;
4. Backend creates a new secure proxy which proxies the IoT device to the end user with authentication;
5. Backend replies to the user with the ip and authorization tokens to connect to the proxy;
6. User connects to the diagnostic session through the proxy;

Now, I found only one solution thus far, which is [Ceryx](https://github.com/sourcelair/ceryx), however, it has no authentication. NGINX plus doesn't seem like an option, due to the significant license costs, but also due to the fact it doesn't seem to be able to handle this.

Are there any solutions besides adjusting Cyrex to support authentication?

Answer (score 0):

With OpenResty you can set up your proxy using:

- [`acces_by_lua`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#access_by_lua) request phase to authenticate your request
- [`balancer_by_lua`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#balancer_by_lua_block) to handle a dynamic proxying

This can be easily achieved, but will require you to write some code.